# Identifying new additions to a comma-delimited string

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 50 rows of comma-delimited data. The number of features contained within the comma-delimited data ***increases from bottom to top*** i.e row 50 (the last row) always has the fewest delimiters, and row 1 (the first row) always has the most delimiters. The number of features increases randomly, and each feature can be either unique or duplicated. Either multiple or single features can be added to the string on each row. The features are placed randomly into the previous rows' comma-delimited string i.e they can be placed into the middle of the string on the previous row, or at the beginning or the end of the previous string. If there are multiple added to a row, they may not be placed together. For example:

```
1  fish,pig,cat,dog,fish,mouse,fish,cow
2  pig,cat,dog,fish,mouse,fish
3  pig,cat,dog,fish,mouse
4  pig,cat,dog,mouse
5  pig,cat,dog,mouse
6  cat,dog,mouse
7  cat,mouse
8  cat,mouse
9  cat 
10
```

I need to extract the feature(s) that have been added to the comma-delimited string on each row, preferably using a UDF. The desired output from the above example would be:

```
1  fish,cow
2  fish
3  fish
4  
5  pig
6  dog
7  
8  mouse
9  cat
10
```

I have had some success using a UDF that compares adjacent rows, and extracts any unique values between the two rows in an adjacent column (i.e if the UDF is used on rows 4 and 5 in B4, B4 will be blank; however, if the UDF is used on rows 3 and 4 in B3, B3 will have the value "fish") . However, this causes problems since some of the features are duplicated (see rows 1 and 2 in the above example). This results in the UDF returning a blank value when a duplicate has been added to the string.

I have had most success with these (very slightly adjusted) UDFs that I found on stack exchange, particularly the former:

```
Function NotThere(BaseText As String, TestText As String) As String
  Dim V As Variant, BaseWords() As String
  NotThere = "" & TestText & ","
  For Each V In Split(BaseText, ",")
    NotThere = Replace(NotThere, V & ",", ",")
  Next
  NotThere = Mid(Application.Trim(NotThere), 3, Len(NotThere) - 0)
End Function
```

and

```
Function Dups(R1 As String, R2 As String) As String
    Dim nstr As String, R As Variant
        For Each R In Split(R2, ",")
            If InStr(R1, Trim(R)) = 0 Then
                nstr = nstr & IIf(nstr = "", R, "," & R)
            End If
        Next R
    Dups = nstr
    End Function
```

I have also tried the method suggested here: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/array-differences.htm, but continually get #VALUE errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iterate both arrays and remove as duplicates are found.  When done return what is left:

```
Function newadd(rng1 As String, rng2 As String) As String
    If rng1 = "" Then
        newadd = rng2
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim spltStr1() As String
    spltStr1 = Split(rng1, ",")

    Dim spltstr2() As String
    spltstr2 = Split(rng2, ",")

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp As String
    For i = LBound(spltstr2) To UBound(spltstr2)
        For j = LBound(spltStr1) To UBound(spltStr1)
            If spltStr1(j) = spltstr2(i) Then
                spltStr1(j) = ""
                spltstr2(i) = ""
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If spltstr2(i) <> "" Then
            temp = temp & "," & spltstr2(i)
        End If
    Next i


    newadd = Mid(temp, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try a scripting dictionary to track your duplicates.

```
Option Explicit

Function NotThere(BaseText As String, TestText As String, _
                  Optional delim As String = ",") As String
    Static dict As Object
    Dim bt As Variant, tt As Variant, i As Long, tmp As String

    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Else
        dict.RemoveAll
    End If
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    tt = Split(TestText, delim)
    bt = Split(BaseText, delim)

    For i = LBound(tt) To UBound(tt)
        If Not dict.exists(tt(i)) Then
            dict.Item(tt(i)) = 1
        Else
            dict.Item(tt(i)) = dict.Item(tt(i)) + 1
        End If
    Next i

    For i = LBound(bt) To UBound(bt)
        If Not dict.exists(bt(i)) Then
            tmp = tmp & delim & bt(i)
        Else
            dict.Item(bt(i)) = dict.Item(bt(i)) - 1
            If Not CBool(dict.Item(bt(i))) Then dict.Remove bt(i)
        End If
    Next i

    NotThere = Mid(tmp, Len(delim) + 1)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Above is marked as the answer but this also works perfectly.

Comment: no worries; this demonstrates a number of scripting.dictionary properties and methods that are not usually used.

Answer (score 2):

**edited** to account for possible features as substrings of other features

you could use this UDF:

```
Public Function NewFeatures(ByVal txt1 As String, txt2 As String) As String
    Dim feat As Variant
    txt1 = "," & txt1 & ","
    For Each feat In Split(txt2, ",")
        txt1 = Replace(txt1, "," & feat & ",", ",,", , 1)
    Next
    NewFeatures = Replace(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Split(txt1, ","), " ")), " ", ",")
End Function
```

Comment: This has the same issue as my (deleted) answer - it fails if words may be substrings of other words.  Eg. "cat", "catfish"

Comment: @TimWilliams, that was not the case of the OP's question, but I edited question to handle that, too

Comment: @bm13563, did you try this?

Comment: @DisplayName Apologies for not responding sooner. I have just tested this now, and I confirm that this does work. I have marked the above as the answer as it was submitted first, but this also works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Out of curiosity, and keeping the accepted answer as it is, which solution are you using?

Comment: I'm using Scott Cramer's, simply because I started implementing it as soon as I was sure that it worked (which was earlier than any of the other responses). I'm also relatively new to VBA, and haven't really used scripting dictionaries, so I wanted to steer clear of Jeeped's just in case I needed to adapt it to my needs.