# substitute words in sentence

Tags: vba, excel, replace, substitution

If cell `A1` contains a values, I want to know how to eliminate it from the sentence (`A2`).

**Example:**

- Without modification (original):

  ```
  A1 = (null)  
  A2 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
  ```
- After modification:

  ```
  if A1 = 2,5,8   
  A2 = 1,3,4,6,7,9
  ```

Comment: Have you looked into the `SUBSTITUTE` function?

Comment: This has been asked and answered as recently as [2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360139/identifying-new-additions-to-a-comma-delimited-string).

Answer (score 0):

After entering values in **A1** and **A2**, run this short macro:

```
Sub removewords()
    Dim veto As Boolean, temp As String
    ary1 = Split([a1], ",")
    ary2 = Split([a2], ",")
    For Each a In ary2
        veto = False
        For Each b In ary1
            If a = b Then veto = True
        Next b
        If Not veto Then temp = temp & "," & a
    Next a
    [a2] = Mid(temp, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used on the the worksheet or in VBA:

```
Function removeWords(words, wordsToExclude) As String
    Dim w: For Each w In Split(words, ",")
        If InStr(wordsToExclude, w) = 0 Then removeWords = removeWords & "," & w
    Next: removeWords = Mid(removeWords, 2)
End Function
```

---

### Example:

To get output matching your example:

[image: img]

...or if you don't want to "hard-code" the source values like that, you can refer to a cell instead, for example:

[image: img]

Either way, the source data has to come from "somewhere", since a worksheet cell can't hold both a value and a formula.  Alternatively, the function could be converted to a subroutine, and then you could execute when needed.